# Missing Oracle Linux (red hat family) Locales

Tags: rhel, locale, oracle-linux

I was logging on to a dev oracle linux 7 system and noticed these warnings when logging in:

```
Last login: Thu Mar 24 15:23:29 2022 from x.x.x.x
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.utf-8)
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.utf-8)
/bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.utf-8)
```

So I check for all the locales on the system and see this; I have only the most basic of system locales.

```
$localectl list-locales
C.utf8

$ locale -a
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.utf8
POSIX
```

The question being, where are all the available locales? and how do I get them back?

I answered my own question below, posting here for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out a developer keen to make a lean system removed them from /usr/lib/locales/locale-archive

Once the locale-archive had its locales removed, a good way to get them back is to retrieve and rebuild archive from the source package (I used yum provides /usr/lib/locales/C.utf8 to figure out which package i needed, glibc-common) and I rebuilt the archive like so:

```
cd /tmp/tempdir
yumdownloader glibc-common
rpm2cpio glibc-common-2.17-325.0.1.el7_9.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv
cp /tmp/tempdir/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive.tmpl usr/lib/locale/locale-archive.tmpl
build-locale-archive
```

Once the archive was rebuilt from the source packages version of the template file I could see all the locales again and the warnings were now gone because the locales could once again be referenced.
This might be a little bit of a sledge hammer approach, I notices from the --help flag of build-locale-archive there is an install option that might allow the more direct install or fix of the missing locales, but by this point i had already rebuilt everything.

Hope this helps someone else in future.

Comment: And the developer saved a whopping 14MB of disk space. Maybe $0.0002 (US) at current SSD pricing.